# How to identify iOS app extension crash in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, ios-app-extension

In my Xamarin project, I have added a new app extension project to the solution. 
It is running fine with it's auto generated default code. But when I change something in the `MainInterface.storyboard` and run again, the extension is not loading; it's crashing with a blink.

I am trying to find the reason for the crash. Since debugging extensions with Xamarin Studio is not possible at the moment, how can I detect the reason for the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use old-school way of debugging things for now, using `NSLog` or `Console.WriteLine`

These logs will show up in the *Device Log* pad in the Xamarin Studio or in System logs if you're testing extensions on simulator

Comment: O, I am using it now. But any way to use breakpoints and debugger directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible at the moment

Comment: :(, I hope this option will come soon. Some tamarin forums I could understand that.